# How can I make some edges of a planar graph of the same or roughly same length?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

This is a small part in a bigger problem I'm trying to do. Assume that I have a planar graph as in the image below. I'm given a list of edges with the same length, `sameLengthEdges`. How can I make these edges same length (or roughly same) while keeping the planar property on the plot and vertices 1 and 2 are always on the bottom?

`allEdge` and `sameLengthEdges` are variables which can be changed. So placing them manually in some fixed coordinates doesn't help.

```
allEdge = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
   5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 
   8 \[UndirectedEdge] 9, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 10, 
   11 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 12 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 10 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 12, 
   6 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 9 \[UndirectedEdge] 11};
sameLengthEdges = {3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 10 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 12, 
   6 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 9 \[UndirectedEdge] 11};
g = Graph[allEdge, GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding", 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]